# Video rewind doesn't work on website with Nginx + http_mp4_module

Tags: video, nginx, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4

I making a video-streaming website, where user can watch videos online. I'm using nginx to serve files, with http_mp4_module enabled. Video format is mp4, moov atom mooved to the beginning of the file.

My nginx location config for mp4:

```
  location ~* \.(mp4)$ {
           mp4;
           mp4_buffer_size     1m;
           mp4_max_buffer_size 5m;
  }
```

Video is playing, but rewind not working, I can't change the playing time.

mp4 mime type exists in **/etc/nginx/mime.types**

I've tried many different videos, that working correctly on the other websites, but not working on mine.

[Here](http://mfcr.boxeus.ru/demo) is an example of my wideo with Video.js player and simple HTML5 player.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on another forum with similar problem that you are facing:

If your MP4 files cannot be seeked before they are completely downloaded, you will have to fix the MOOV atom (it contains the seeking information) located at the end of your video. Use this little application to parse your videos and add the necessary cue points.

The application name is [QTIndexSwapper 2](http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/).

Hope this information helps. Forum [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/383917/nginx-mp4-videos-not-seeking-and-starting-immediately).